# HelmetJS Content Security Policy refusing to apply inline style even with a nonce

Tags: node.js, reactjs, helmet.js

I've been using helmet to implement Content-Security-Policy and have not had any problems until I upgraded the Node version I was using from 6 to 16.

I return a styled HTML element when the app first loads, and I use a nonce on the style tag. After upgrading node versions, nothing loads and I see this message in the browser console:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-uXeTuzCq2Sp5MWrSBuypzA=='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Here is the CSP configuration that I am currently using with helmet.

```
const sources = [];
sources.push((req, res) => `'nonce-${res.cspNonce}'`);
sources.push("'self'");

app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: sources,
      scriptSrc: sources,
      styleSrc: sources,
      frameAncestors: sources
    }
  })
);
```

I've tried different configurations for the directives but nothing is working.

I'm confused because the error message in the console suggests using a nonce, but I am using one. In the network tab I can see the CSP on the header and there is a nonce on the style tag as expected.

Comment: Helmet.js maintainer here. I'm not sure what's going wrong, but it might be that your nonces don't match. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_inline_script for an example of how to use it with `<script>`s, which is similar with `<style>`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up not being an issue with helmet, but with styled-components, a dependency of a front end library that was added along with the Node upgrade. I just had to add a __webpack_nonce__ along with the existing nonces and everything worked as expected.